# Проблема с urlopen в urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

При использовании модуля из интернета выдаётся ошибка:

> В модуле urllib не найден метод urlopen.

Я исправил эту проблему, но в итоге появилась еще одна:

> http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Comment: Вы не смотрели документацию по urllib?

Comment: Нет, не смотрел

Comment: Приведите Ваш код, пожалуйста. Иначе [**вряд ли качественный ответ получите**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Спасибо.

Comment: ограничивайтесь одной ошибкой на вопрос. Если вам одну ошибку исправили, и вы обнаружили ещё ошибки и не можете их самостоятельно исправить, чтение документации, поиск в гугле не показывают решения, то задайте *отдельный* Stack Overflow вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html):

> The urllib module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to
>   urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will
>   automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.
>   Also note that the urllib.request.urlopen() function in Python 3 is
>   equivalent to urllib2.urlopen() and that urllib.urlopen() has been
>   removed.

Замените

```
from urllib import urlopen
```

на

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

или на

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib import urlopen
```

для сохранения совместимости с Python2

Comment: Спасибо за помощь
И да, код был написан еще во времена второго питона, но я использовал его для третьего(я тупой, да)

Comment: ЧОРТ
ТЕПЕРЬ ЕЩЕ БОЛЬШЕ ОШИБОК

Comment: @ДаниилСереда наверняка в вашем коде это была не единственная несовместимость с Python3.

Comment: Если я скину код, вы сможете сказать, в чем ошибка?

Comment: @ДаниилСереда нет, таким я не занимаюсь. На Stackoverflow вы вряд ли найдёте кого-либо, кто согласиться заняться портированием вашего кода.